# Multi streamin from a single stream NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, streaming, node-modules

`
*The code works, it takes the stream from an external source and sends it to multiple users connected at the same time.

The external server accepts a single request, so I can't create a fetch() for every single user

I'm using the library 'node-fetch'

PROBLEM:
If user 1 has a bad connection compared to subsequent users, the data flow for subsequent users is blocked waiting for the slowest connection.
From what I've seen, subsequent users who connect are served with the video stream later in time than the first.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:
run fetch() detached from the first user's request,
but if I insert .pipe() outside fetch() it doesn't work.
how can I solve it?
`

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

var userOnline = 0;
//
var streamFlowVideo = {};
var abortControlSignal = {};
var abortControlSignalList = [];


var controller = new AbortController();
var signal = controller.signal;

// if checks if it is the first request, if true creates the first call
if(userOnline == 0) {
   userOnline++; // add to counter
   
   

   var url = 'http://site_of_origin.com/file/video.mp4';

   fetch(url, {
       headers: {'User-Agent': 'MY USER AGENT'},
       method: 'get',
       signal: signal,
       redirect: 'follow',
   })
   .then(r => {
       abortControlSignal[channelTemp] = controller;
       streamFlowVideo[channelTemp] = r.body;
       
       (streamFlowVideo[channelTemp]).pipe(response);
    })
    .catch(e => {
       ( function() { // timeout 5 second
        return response.status(500).send('Error.');
            }, 5000);
    });
                  
}else{
    (streamFlowVideo[channelTemp]).pipe(response);
}


req.on('close', function() {
        if(userOnline == 1) { // this closes the stream if the last user also closes the connection.
        userOnline = 0;
        (abortControlSignal[channelTemp]).abort(); // close steaming
        delete abortControlSignal[channelTemp];
        delete streamFlowVideo[channelTemp];
    }

});
```